# How to use macro in WHERE statement in PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas

```
 %let CHECK_DATE = %sysfunc(SUM(&end_of_period.,1),yymmdd10.); 

 proc sql; 
            select * from table1
            where Source_Date < input(&CHECK_DATE.,yymmdd10.);  

 quit;
```

&CHECK_DATE is a date macro in the format of '2015-12-31';

Source_Date is the SAS date value.

I get this error when I try to run this code.  Not sure why...

```
           _
           22
            _
            200
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, (, +, -, BTRIM, CALCULATED, CASE, EXISTS, INPUT, NOT, PUT, SUBSTRING, TRANSLATE, USER, ^, ~.  

ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.


           _
           22
           76
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <, <=, <>, =, >, >=, ?, AND, BETWEEN, 
              CONTAINS, EQ, EQT, GE, GET, GT, GTT, IN, IS, LE, LET, LIKE, LT, LTT, NE, NET, NOT, NOTIN, OR, ^, ^=, |, ||, ~, ~=.  

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a table in a `FROM` statement there?  Otherwise, there's nothing specifically wrong with your code, assuming `'2015-12-31'` is exactly (with quotes and all) the contents of `&check_Date`.

Comment: Yes, there was a table name.  It got cut off when I was pasting.  But, even with the table name, I'm still getting an error when I run...

And, when I check the log, &CHECK_DATE doesn't even show the value it contains.  IT just says &CHECK_DATE.  I also tried %put &CHECK_DATE. to see if there was a value inside.

Comment: Post the full code and log please

Comment: That `%sysfunc` bit won't work properly.  It needs a function.  You can use `PUTN` as the function, I suppose, though why go through putting then inputting??

Answer (score 2):

I assume it is just because you have not put quotes around your character literal that you passing to the `INPUT()` function.

This code runs.

```
data table1;
  source_date=date();
  format source_date yymmdd10.;
run;

%let end_of_period=%sysfunc(date());
%put &=end_of_period ;

%let CHECK_DATE = %sysfunc(SUM(&end_of_period.,1),yymmdd10.);
%put &=check_date ;

proc sql;
  select * from table1
    where Source_Date < input("&CHECK_DATE",yymmdd10.)
  ;
quit;
```

But it would be much easier to not use `&CHECK_DATE` and just code the where clause using `&END_OF_PERIOD`.

```
proc sql;
  select * from table1
    where Source_Date < &end_of_period + 1
  ;
quit;
```